# How to have a user exit a long discord command when they want?

Tags: python, discord.py

In my discord bot I have some code that asks the user for input a couple of times in one command, Is there a way to have another bot command when triggered stops the current command or even forces the bot to stop running and restart entirely? Here is some of my smaller code, I would like to keep the same formatting and everything, just a command to break out of that command.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Betauri Members")
async def wsadd(ctx):

async def get_input_of_type(func): 
    global sentdex_guild
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
            return func(msg.content)
        except ValueError:
            continue
def check(m):
    return m.content == m.content and m.channel == channel and m.author == ctx.author
channel = ctx.channel

await channel.send('type your ign, example...')
await channel.send('aaaafireball')
await channel.send('(dont retype $wslist)')
name = await get_input_of_type(str)
name = name+':'

await channel.send('type bs mods, example...')
await channel.send('bs: battery10,delta4,tw1,barrier1')
bs = await get_input_of_type(str)

await channel.send('type first support ship mods, example...')
await channel.send('miner: tw1,genesis1')
sup1 = await get_input_of_type(str)

await channel.send('type second support ship mods, example...')
await channel.send('trans: tw1,dispatch1')
sup2 = await get_input_of_type(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your check such that it raises an exception instead of returning a falsy value when it sees certain kinds of messages:

```
class AbortWait(Exception):
    pass

def check(m):
    if m.content == 'abort':
        raise AbortWait
    return m.content == m.content and m.channel == channel and m.author == ctx.author
```

You can also handle the error in the error handler if you want special behaviour after the command has ended

```
@wsadd.error
async def wadd_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError) and isinstance(error.original, AbortWait):
        await ctx.send("Command aborted")
    else:
        raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ..

What about an `if` statment after each step to check if the user wants to exit or not ?

Just like :

```py
if(user_input.upper() == "QUIT"):
   return
```